# Button click does not redirect to another page

Tags: php

```
<script language=javascript>
function validate()
{
    document.form1.action="validate.php";
    document.form1.submit();    
}
function delete()
{
    document.form1.action="delete.php";
    document.form1.submit();
}
</script>
<body>
while($s=mysql_fetch_row($q))
{
    echo "<form name=form1 method=post>
<table width=90% bgcolor='#6CDAF5' align=center>
  <tr><th align=left> Bug $i: </tr>
  <tr><td>Username: <td> <input type=text value='$s[0]' name=username> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>User email-id: <td><input type=text value='$s[1]' name=email> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>User Contact-no :<td><input type=text value='$s[2]' name=contactno> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Bug: <td><textarea rows=5 cols=40 name=bug>$s[3]</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Bug-Reason: <td><textarea rows=5 cols=40  name=text1>$s[4]</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Bug-Solution:<td><textarea rows=5 cols=40 name=text2>$s[5]</textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Updated-date:<td><input type=text value='$s[6]' name=date></td></tr>
  <tr><td width=100% align=right colspan=2><input type=submit value='add this bug with main bugs' OnClick='validate()' >

<input type=submit name=delete value='delete this bug' OnClick=delete()></tr>
  </table><br></form>";


}

    </body>
```

I created two buttons as `"add this bug with main bug"` and `"delete this bug"`, while clicking this button, it has to redirect to `validate.php` and `delete.php` respectively.

I mentioned that in Javascript, but when I click those buttons it doesn't redirect to another page.

Comment: `return false;` to avoid the default action.

Comment: If your form works correctly only with JS enabled anyways, then you should use `input type=button` (instead of `submit`) and trigger submitting the form using `onclick` on them. (With your solution right now, the browser submits the form “the old-fashioned way” on click, and therefor your JS code likely has no time to take effect.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html#link4

Answer (score 3):

The return value of your `OnClick` event handlers must be `false` in order to prevent the default action for a `submit` type of input (which is to submit the form).

You can make the value of the OnClick event handlers `return validate()` or `return delete()` and then make your JS functions `return false;` at the very end.

Or, change `type=submit` to `type=button` as the latter type has no default action.

Comment: can u give me corrected program sir pls...  i couldnt understand u

Answer (score 2):

To have a form redirect to two action pages,you will have to something like this

```
function redirect()
{   
    if(document.value=="validate")
       {
               document.form.action="validate.php";
       }
       else if(document.value=="delete")
       {
               document.form.action="delete.php";
       }
       return true;
}
<form method=\"post\" name=\"form\" style=display:inline onsubmit=\"return 
                                                              redirect();\">
...
<input type=submit id=validate  onclick='document.value=this.value' value='validate' 
                                                                  name='validate'>
<input type=submit  id=delete   onclick='document.value=this.value' value='delete' 
                                                                   name='delete'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function delete()
{
    document.form1.action="delete.php";
    document.form1.submit();
    return false; // stop page from submitting 
}
```